# How do I generate the given sinusoidal ON/OFF waveform in Matlab/Simulink?

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, simulink, trigonometry

I want to implement the following signal:

[Required input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ctLTF.jpg)

I(t) = 500*(sin(pi.t/0.3))^2, t belongs {0,Ts}

= 0, t belongs {Ts,T}

Here, T = 0.8 and Ts = 0.3

The code I tried:

```
t = 0.01 * [0:3000]';         
d = 0.8 * [0:35]';           
y = pulstran(t,d,'rectpuls',0.3);
ut = 500.*((sin(pi*(t-floor(t/0.8)*0.8)/0.3)).^2).*y;
plot(t,ut)
```

The waveform generated has several errors, including two peaks per ON state.  Please help to rectify.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qoOus.jpg)

Comment: I haven't checked your code in detail, but why do you expect it not to have 2 peaks in an ON period? The period of your pulse is 0.8, with 0.3 ON, then 0.5 OFF. The period of the sin^2 wave is 0.3. 0.3 doesn't go into 0.8, so your sine waves and pulses aren't going to stay 'lined up'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are wanting a ***repeating*** pattern of a squared sine wave (for 0.3s) followed by a zero (for 0.5s).

That can be achieved with the following:

```
>> Io = 500;
>> Ts = 0.3;
>> T = 0.8;
>> SampleRate = 0.01;
>> tOnePeriod = 0:SampleRate:(T-SampleRate);
>> yOnePeriod = zeros(1,numel(tOnePeriod));
>> yOnePeriod(tOnePeriod<=Ts) = Io*(sin(pi*tOnePeriod(tOnePeriod<=Ts)/Ts).^2);
>> simin.time=[];
>> simin.signals.values=yOnePeriod(:);
>> simin.signals.dimenions = [1 1];
```

If you want to check the generated signal in MATLAB then do the following:

```
>> plot(tOnePeriod,yOnePeriod)
```

Import the signal into Simulink in the following way:

[image]

Some important points about the *From Workspace* block:

1. The simin variable deliberately has no time points specified
2. The sample time for the block has been changed from its default
3. Interpolate Data has been de-selected
4. *Form output after final data value* has been set to *Cyclic Repetition*.